# SQL Loop value, if previous value was higher add this to the subsequent rows

Tags: sql, loops, t-sql

I have to do a calculation on a database table (I cannot create any columns in the database).

Issue: 
For each socket if the value drops lower than the 'previous recorded value', I will need to add the 'current row value' to the 'previous recorded value'.

I had tried a solution (based on the value falling to zero - this logic is incorrect - in the data there seems to be some sockets where the value does not fall to zero and can be 0.001)

Code which does NOT cover the scenarios where the value is not exactly zero

```
with data as
(
   select 
     read_at,
     socket_id,
     energy,
     case 
       when energy < 0 
       then lag(energy,1) over(partition by socket_id order by read_at asc)
       else energy 
     end output
   FROM [Sandpit].[dbo].[Energy1]
   where read_at is not null
), additions as
(
  select *
  from data
  where energy < 0
), latest as
(
  select d.*,
     isnull(a.output,0) roll_total
  from data d
  left join additions a 
     on a.read_at = d.read_at and a.socket_id = d.socket_id
)
select l.*,
  sum(roll_total) over(partition by socket_id order by read_at asc) rolling_total,
  energy+sum(roll_total) over(partition by socket_id order by read_at asc)  true_output
from latest l
order by 2 asc, 1 asc
```

Sample Data added - sorry I was going to do this via an attachment but I can't find the option:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Energy](
    [read_at] [datetime] NULL,
    [socket_id] [float] NULL,
    [energy ] [float] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
INSERT [dbo].[Energy] ([read_at], [socket_id], [energy ]) VALUES (CAST(N'2019-10-18 13:01:01.000' AS DateTime), 1, 0.1)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Energy] ([read_at], [socket_id], [energy ]) VALUES (CAST(N'2019-10-18 13:01:05.000' AS DateTime), 1, 0.3)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Energy] ([read_at], [socket_id], [energy ]) VALUES (CAST(N'2019-10-18 13:01:07.000' AS DateTime), 1, 0.5)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Energy] ([read_at], [socket_id], [energy ]) VALUES (CAST(N'2019-10-18 13:01:09.000' AS DateTime), 1, 0.6)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Energy] ([read_at], [socket_id], [energy ]) VALUES (CAST(N'2019-10-18 13:01:11.000' AS DateTime), 1, 1)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Energy] ([read_at], [socket_id], [energy ]) VALUES (CAST(N'2019-10-19 13:01:15.000' AS DateTime), 1, 0)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Energy] ([read_at], [socket_id], [energy ]) VALUES (CAST(N'2019-10-19 13:01:18.000' AS DateTime), 1, 0.3)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Energy] ([read_at], [socket_id], [energy ]) VALUES (CAST(N'2019-10-25 13:01:20.000' AS DateTime), 1, 0.5)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Energy] ([read_at], [socket_id], [energy ]) VALUES (CAST(N'2019-10-26 13:01:22.000' AS DateTime), 1, 0.7)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Energy] ([read_at], [socket_id], [energy ]) VALUES (CAST(N'2019-10-27 13:01:25.000' AS DateTime), 1, 0)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Energy] ([read_at], [socket_id], [energy ]) VALUES (CAST(N'2019-10-27 13:02:26.000' AS DateTime), 1, 0.2)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Energy] ([read_at], [socket_id], [energy ]) VALUES (CAST(N'2019-10-27 13:01:03.000' AS DateTime), 1, 0.3)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Energy] ([read_at], [socket_id], [energy ]) VALUES (CAST(N'2019-10-27 13:02:26.000' AS DateTime), 1, 0.0012)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Energy] ([read_at], [socket_id], [energy ]) VALUES (CAST(N'2019-10-27 13:01:03.000' AS DateTime), 1, 0.1)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Energy] ([read_at], [socket_id], [energy ]) VALUES (CAST(N'2019-10-18 13:01:05.000' AS DateTime), 2, 0.3)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Energy] ([read_at], [socket_id], [energy ]) VALUES (CAST(N'2019-10-18 13:01:07.000' AS DateTime), 2, 0.5)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Energy] ([read_at], [socket_id], [energy ]) VALUES (CAST(N'2019-10-18 13:01:09.000' AS DateTime), 2, 0.6)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Energy] ([read_at], [socket_id], [energy ]) VALUES (CAST(N'2019-10-18 13:01:11.000' AS DateTime), 2, 1)
GO
```

[image: Example Data Return]

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: consider formatting your code so that it is more readable, remember -- you are asking people to ready your code -- why not make it look nice?

Comment: @hogan I did try added ''' but was not able to do it .. sorry

Comment: @GordonLinoff - I have added it in, thank you

Comment: @aarion -- ok I did it for you as an example -- note how there are no random tabs and spaces.  Like elements line up.  Open and close elements have the same indent.  There is no extra spaces for no reason before syntax elements etc.  This is what well formatted code looks like.  Do you see how it is easier to understand?

Comment: @Hogan - Thank you, my code in the IDE was formatted although not as nicely as yours but when I added it to the post it was being translated into a paragraph. I addedd ''' before and after the code block which did not work. Could you please tell me what I should have added instead please for suture reference. Is it Cntrl + k

Comment: @GordonLinoff _ have added an image of the desired output. Thank you again for your help

Comment: @Aarion -- oh that part is easy -- the text box has a button at the top `{}` -- select the code you want to keep monspace formatted and hit that button.

Comment: @Hogan - thank you and apologies for you having to format it.

Answer (score 0):

> For each socket if the value drops lower than the 'previous recorded value', I will need to add the 'current row value' to the 'previous recorded value'.

Based on this description, I would envision:

```
select s.*,
       (case when value < lag(value) over (partition by socket order by datetime)
             then value + lag(value) over (partition by socket order by datetime)
             else value
        end) as new_value
from sockets s;
```

This is a literal interpretation of what you are describing.

Comment: Thank you: I ran this:  
select s.*,
       (case when [energy ] < lag([energy ]) over (partition by socket_id order by [read_at])
             then [energy ] + lag([energy ]) over (partition by socket_id order by [read_at])
             else [energy ]
        end) as new_value
from [Sandpit].[dbo].[Energy] s;

Comment: The desired result is:Issue: 
  < If the energy value becomes less than take the previous energy value 
 2019-10-19 13:01:15.000: Output value will be Calculation 1 + 0)
 2019-10-19 13:01:18.000:  Output value will be 1 + energy (0.3)
 2019-10-25 13:01:20.000    Output value will be 1 + energy (0.5)